# Como reconstruir o XML de um layout Fragment, quando ela for expandida?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragment

Eu tenho uma tela com um fragment, que sem estar expandida, ela apenas mostra o campo usuario e senha e o botão cadastrar, e eu queria que quando expandisse ela, campos como nome, data de nascimento, municipio, estado, fossem inseridos entre o campo senha e o botao cadastrar, lembrando que ela se expande quando o usuario for incluir no campo usuario.

XML da fragment ta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_novo_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/campoEmailNovoUsuario" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/campoSenhaNovo" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_mostrar_senha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/chk_mostrar_senha"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_termos_criar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/email_criar_button" style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:text="@string/acao_nova_conta"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/branco"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_arredondado"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

isso é tudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *layout* da *activity* adicione um *FrameLayout* no local onde quer que seja apresentado o conteúdo do *fragment*:

```
.....
.....
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder">
</FrameLayout>  
.....
.....
```

Quando quiser "expandir" o *fragment* execute o seguinte código:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new Sua_Classe_Fragment());
    ft.commit();
```